# Querying a DataFrame values from a specific year

Tags: pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe I have created from weather data that shows the high and low temperatures by day from 2005-2015. I want to be able to query my dataframe such that it only shows the values with the year 2015. Is there any way to do this without first changing the datetime values to only show year (i.e. not making strtime(%y) only first)?

**DataFrame Creation:**

```
df=pd.read_csv('data/C2A2_data/BinnedCsvs_d400/fb441e62df2d58994928907a91895ec62c2c42e6cd075c2700843b89.csv')
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%m-%d-%y')
```

**Attempt to Query:**

```
daily_df=df[df['Date']==datetime.date(year=2015)]
Error: asks for a month and year to be specified.
```

**Data:**

An NOAA dataset has been stored in the file data/C2A2_data/BinnedCsvs_d400/fb441e62df2d58994928907a91895ec62c2c42e6cd075c2700843b89.csv. The data for this assignment comes from a subset of The National Centers for Environmental Information (NCEI) Daily Global Historical Climatology Network (GHCN-Daily). The GHCN-Daily is comprised of daily climate records from thousands of land surface stations across the globe.

Each row in the assignment datafile corresponds to a single observation.

The following variables are provided to you:

```
id : station identification code
date : date in YYYY-MM-DD format (e.g. 2012-01-24 = January 24, 2012)
element : indicator of element type
TMAX : Maximum temperature (tenths of degrees C)
TMIN : Minimum temperature (tenths of degrees C)
value : data value for element (tenths of degrees C)
```

Image of DataFrame:

[image]

Comment: you can do: `daily_df = df[df['Date'].dt.year == 2015].reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: Hello, that did not seem to work. I am receiving the error 'AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values'

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding a row with just the year and then querying that way but there has to be a better way to do this?

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%d-%m-%y')
df['Year']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%y')
daily_df = df[df['Year']=='15']
return daily_df
```